# How to enable the bookmarks toolbar in Pentadactyl/Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, pentadactyl

I am using Pentadactyl Nightly (20 August 2013) with Firefox 23.0.1. After installing Pentadactyl, it removed all my toolbars. However, the bookmarks toolbar is actually useful for me so I want to enable it.

I am able to enable it with the Firefox menu (or `:tbs bookmarks`), but even after `:mkp!` the bookmarks toolbar disappears again when I restart Firefox.

I'd like the bookmarks toolbar to always be visible. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

If you use linux, try to put this in your ${HOME}/.pentadactylrc:

> set guioptions=B

If you use windows, try to put that line in _pentadactylrc under your HOME.

Comment: you can also type above command in the console of the pentadactyl and then type mkpentadactylrc in your console. It will write it to the pentadctyl_rc file in any OS. Avoids the hassle. But the right way is the above one.

Comment: You need to use `set guioptions+=B`, otherwise you will replace the current setting instead of appending to it. The default setting is `bCrs`, which means show bottom scrollbar, always show command line (outside of status line), right scrollbar, and status bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind it to a key:

```
map e :toolbartoggle Bookmarks Toolbar<CR>
```